# Pyspark: collect dataframe to list taking time

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to collet data of a dataframe into a list after applying some spark transformations and applying `pandasUDF`.
The issue is after applying `pandasUDF`, the collect process takes too much time.
My dataframe, df, has around 5 col like id,address etc.

**my code**:

```py
df = df.groupBy("col_name").apply(pandas_udf_function)
df.show()

id_list = list(df.select('*').toPandas()['col_name'])
print(id_list)
```

This line takes around 700 sec to execute if I apply `pandasUDF` on my dataframe.
This same line takes around 10 sec if I don't apply `pandasUDF` on the dataframe.

**Is there** any way I can collect dataframe into a list faster?
p.s. - I have already tried the `collect()` method, It's taking almost the same time.

Comment: Spark is lazy. The line you refer to only takes time because it triggers all the transformations you called before. So most likely, it IS the application of the UDF (which are very slow in pyspark) that takes all that time. Can you share enough code to reproduce your problem?

Comment: @Oli: thankyou for your comment. I have used 'show' on my dataframe to ensure all the the transformations have been applied before collecting df in a list. please look and suggest any solution.

Comment: @utkarshdixit, it looks like you're only collecting a list for that specific column `col_name` which you did groupby on. Is the Pandas UDF necessary for this?

Comment: @rchome - I filter my dataframe based on my pandas udf function, which I didn't show here. I need to use this pandasUDF as some Data Science model runs in it.

Comment: @utkarshdixit I see. As @Oli mentioned, it's likely that the `pandasUDF` is causing the slowdown, so we would need to check if the `pandasUDF` can be optimized.

Comment: @rchome : I guess you are right. It is the pandasUDF that is taking this much time.Thanks